# What is test class for below code?

Tags: apex, trigger, unit-test, code-coverage, test-setup

public class UtilityClass {
public static String getDescribedObjects( List lstSObjectType ) {

```
    // Globally desribe all the objects 
    Map<String, SObjectType> globalDescribe = Schema.getGlobalDescribe(); 
    // Create a JSON string with object field labels and picklist values
    String allObjJSON = '{';
    
    // Iterate over the list of objects and describe each object  
    for( String sObjectType : lstSObjectType ) {
        
        if( allObjJSON != '{' ) 
          allObjJSON += ', ';
        allObjJSON += '"' + sObjectType + '": ';
        DescribeSObjectResult describeResult = globalDescribe.get(sObjectType).getDescribe();
        Map<String, Schema.SObjectField> desribedFields = describeResult.fields.getMap();
        String objJSON = '{';
        
        for( String fieldName :  desribedFields.keySet() ) {
            
            // Descirbe the field 
            Schema.SObjectField field = desribedFields.get( fieldName );
            Schema.DescribeFieldResult f = field.getDescribe();     
            if( objJSON != '{' )
                objJSON += ', ';    
            // Get the field label and append in the JSON string
            objJSON += '"' + f.getName() + '": ' + '{ "label" : "' + f.getLabel() + '"';
            
            // if it's a picklist field then also add the picklist options
            if( field.getDescribe().getType() == Schema.DisplayType.PICKLIST ){
                
                List <Schema.PicklistEntry> picklistValues = field.getDescribe().getPickListValues();
              List<String> pickListOptions = new List<String>();
                pickListOptions.add('{ "label": "--None--", "value": null }');
                
                for (Schema.PicklistEntry pe : picklistValues) { 
                    
                    pickListOptions.add('{ "label": "' + pe.getLabel() + '", "value": "' + pe.getValue() + '" }');
                
                }
                
                System.debug( '>>>> ' + fieldName + '>>>> ' + String.join(pickListOptions, ', ') );
                objJSON += ', "picklistOptions": [' + String.join(pickListOptions, ', ') + ']';   
            }
            objJSON += '}';
        }
        objJSON += '}';
        
        allObjJSON += objJSON;
    }
    
    // Close the object in the JSON String
    allObjJSON += '}';
    
    System.debug( ' JSON STRING : ' + allObjJSON );
    
    return allObjJSON;
}
```

}

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange. Please take our [tour] and read through [ask] and [help/on-topic] to get an understanding of our format. We're happy to help with specific problems, but we are not a code-writing service.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To the minimum here is what you can write:

```
    @isTest
public class YourTestClassName {
    @isTest public static void getDescribedObjectsTest(){
        Test.startTest();
        Map<String, object> result = (Map<String, object>)JSON.deserializeUntyped(YourClassName.getDescribedObjects(new List<String>{'Contact','Account'}));
        Test.stopTest();
        System.assert(result!=null, 'Error occurred while describing sObjects.');
        System.assert(result.containsKey('Contact'),'Error occurred while describing Contact object.');
        System.assert(result.containsKey('Account'),'Error occurred while describing Account object.');
    } 
}
```

It covers 100%. It will check if the method has returned Contact and Account sObject details. To check if it contains all the fields you need to extend this logic to fit your result structure.

Hack here is: You need to deserialize the result string into readable output format and then check if the result contains expected data. I have provided a single liner to deserialize the top-level JSON keys into Map<String, Object>. You need to deserialize the child elements into Map or Wrapper and perform assets on them.

Thanks!

Comment: give a man a fish and you feed him for a day; teach a man to fish and you feed him for a lifetime

Comment: @PranayJaiswal Thanks for the advice. Peace.

Answer (score -1):

@IsTest(seeAllData = false)
public class UtilityClass_Test {

@IsTest
static void setup(){

List strlist = new List();
strlist.add('Account');
strlist.add('Contact');
UtilityClass.getDescribedObjects(strlist);
}
}